# The information or simply information

Tags: articles

Should I use the definite article in this sentence: "We have to spread **information**/**the information** concerning the danger of animals' extinction"

Answer (score 9):

Either *information* or *the information* can be used.
Use it without an article if you mean information generally.
Use *the information* if you have specific information in mind, especially if you have already mentioned specific items of information.